# Theory test iterations with none constant type parameters don't show as separate iterations in the Test Explorer

Tags: c#, xunit, test-explorer

I have been writing unit tests in an `xUnit` project for a .NET project. Because I had a lot of combinations of parameters for the same test (3000+) I decided to use the `[ClassData(typeof(TestDataEnumerable))]` in order to have the different options be generated.

The first test has only two parameters, both `enums` (constants which is important later). The second test contains a third `params` parameter which are of type `object`.

When I run the tests in VS Test Explorer I get this output for the tests (not actual code).

```
Namespace.FirstTest.GivenPrecondition_WhenCondition_ThenMethodReturns(firstParam:Standard, secondParam: Denied)
Namespace.SecondTest.GivenPrecondition_WhenCondition_ThenMethodReturns(firstParam: Standard, secondParam: Denied, thirdParams: [ObjectToStringResult, ObjectToStringResult])
```

As well as the Test Explorer showing a dropdown under the test method with each of the Theory iterations for the First Test. But it doesn't show all the iterations for the second test (with the non-constant parameter - the fact that it is a params doesn't affect this, test with just allowed a single object type).

```
TestClass >
   > First Test
       - IterationOne
       - IterationTwo
   Second Test
```

As well as this the XML output from XunitXML.TestLogger cuts the names off before the parameters are shown when it contains a none constant type.

[image]

The code for one such test is below, Permission is just a class containing a Name. It is a class rather than just a string value to allow inheritance I believe so can't be changed to a constant type.

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(PermissionPermutations))]
public void GivenUser_WhenUserHasCorrectPermissions_LoggedInMenuReturnsExpectedMenuItems(EUserType userType, ERovUserType rovUserType, params Permission[] permissions)
{
    var user = UserBuilder.Create(userType, rovUserType)
        .WithPermissions(permissions)
        .Build();

    var results = GetActualResults(user);
    var expected = GetExpectedResults(user);
    
    Assert.Equal(result.Count(), expected.Count());
    Assert.All(results, (name) => Assert.Contains(name, expected));
    Assert.All(expected, (name) => Assert.Contains(name, result));
}

public class PermissionPermutations : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var (userType, rovUserType) in UserTypeConstants.GetAllCombinations())
        {
            foreach (var permission in PermissionConstants.AllPermissions)
            {
                yield return new object[] { userType, rovUserType, permission };
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

The PermissionConstants class looks like this so a total of 88 permissions exist (I tested it with a few thousand iterations and it's not the number of iterations that causes the Explorer to hide the iterations):

```
public static class PermissionConstants
{
    public static Permission[] AllPermissions => new[]
    {
        new Permission { Name = "CanViewUsers" },
        new Permission { Name = "CanEditUsers" },
        ... there are 88 of these total
    };
}
```

And the UserTypeConstants class looks like this, I've changed the names of the enums for privacy, but theEUserType and ERovUserType are just enums:

```
public static class UserTypeConstants
{
    public static EUserType[] AllUserTypes => new[]
    {
        EUserType.Standard,
        EUserType.Admin,
        EUserType.Restricted,
        EUserType.SuperUser,
        EUserType.SystemUser
    };

    public static ERovUserType[] AllRovUserTypes => new[]
    {
        ERovUserType.Level0,
        ERovUserType.Level1,
        ERovUserType.Level2,
        ERovUserType.Level3,
        ERovUserType.Level4,
        ERovUserType.Level5
    };

    public static IEnumerable<(EUserType, ERovUserType)> GetAllCombinations() {
        foreach (var userType in AllUserTypes)
        {
            foreach(var rovUserType in AllRovUserTypes)
            {
                yield return (userType, rovUserType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post please the code of your test.

Comment: Added an example as requested. Thanks for taking a look, let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not reproducible in my example. I am able to see all cases. Which test explorer do you use?

Comment: I'm just using the built in Test Explorer that VS has, I think it's MSTest for building them. I'll add an example of what the PermissionConstants looks like as well as that might help.

Comment: oh... now I can see that. Let me investigate

Comment: It happens because of Permission custom class in the test parameters. Even if you have only one parameter with your custom type (struct, class) and just few cases - you will still not be able to see those cases in the test explorer. Sorry, but I have no idea why that happens. May be you should ask xUnit developers.